# Is everything an object in Scala?

Tags: scala

A literal is an object in Scala, so if you store that into a variable such as val x: Int = 5; would this make this an object as well? Everything seems like to be an object in Scala for some reason.

Comment: > _"Scala is a pure object-oriented language in the sense that every value is an object."_ - [The introduction of the language](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html). So yes, what is the problem with that?

Comment: Well, not everything is an object on the JVM - that `Int` you mentioned can be represented by a primitive `int`, but at the language level, yeah, you can treat everything as an object.

Answer (score 1):

> A literal is an object in Scala,

Well. "Literal" is a property of the source code, mostly. As such, the idea of "being an object" doesn't really apply.

What *is* correct is that every literal *evaluates to* an object.

So, the literal `1` in a source file is not really an object. It is just part of the source code. But it *evaluates to* an object, namely an instance of the class `scala.Int` that represents the mathematical idea of the integer **1**.

> so if you store that into a variable such as val x: Int = 5; would this make this an object as well?

What do you mean by "this"?

`x` is not an object, it is a *variable*. In Scala, like in almost every other language, variables are not objects themselves, rather they are *names* for objects. (Technically, a variable *references* an object.)

`Int` is not an object, either, it is a *type*. Types aren't objects. It is possible, however, that a *type* and a *term* have the *same name*, and the reason why that works is precisely because types aren't objects and thus there can never be any confusion about whether you are talking about the type or the term.

Now, `5` in this expression *is* an object, or more precisely, as we have seen above, it is an *integer literal* with evaluates to an object.